# sed fails with many -e statments

Tags: bash, sed, unix-text-processing

I have huge (12G, 5.9G 1.1G,57M) files that I need to massage into submission in order to successfully run in MySQL-Shell for import.
I dont have a choice on how the files were created they were zipped up and landed on my desk. So I tried and was getting good results
with one or two off "sed" statements. But when I try with many as you see below It slows to a crawl and fails sometimes.
Sadly every one of these sed statements are needed.
I am using some powerful 40 core machines with 252G RAM to process this so I dont believe it is the machine.
Can someone recommend how best to accomplish this many search and replacements? Maybe I am using the wrong language to do this (sed)? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
 ls -Sr ${_WORKING_DIR} | grep -P "^_insert_.*_.*.sql$" \
 | grep -v "_indexlog\|_sessions" \
 | xargs grep -l "),(" \
 | while read F; do \
 sed -E -i \
 -e 's/\),\(/\n/g' \
 -e "s/','/', '/g" \
 -e "s/^INSERT\sINTO\s\`.*\`\sVALUES\s*\((.*)\);$/\1/g" \
 -e "s/, null/, NULL/g" \
 -e 's/,NULL,/, NULL,/g' \
 -e "s/NULL,'/NULL, '/g" \
 -e "s/NULL,NULL/NULL, NULL/g" \
 -e "s/,NULL$/, NULL/g" \
 -e "s/',NULL/', NULL/g" \
 -e "s/',1,'/', 1, '/g" \
 -e "s/',0,'/', 0, '/g" \
 -e "s/('.*',)([0-9])/\1 \2/g" \
 -e "s/^([0-9]{0,9},)('.*)$/\1 \2/g" \
 -e "s/^(.*',)[^\s]([0-9]{0,9}.*)$/\1 \2/g" \
 -e "s/,1,/, 1, /g" \
 -e "s/(.*[0-9]{1}),'/\1, '/g" \
 -e "s/([0-9]{1}),([0-9]{1})/\1, \2/g" \
 -e "s/NULL,([[:digit:]])/NULL, \1/g" \
 $F; \
 echo "File has been worked with sed: $F" >> ${_LOG_FILE}; \
 done
```

Example file content:

```
 INSERT INTO `sessions` VALUES ('6799bfac-e716-4a23-b5f3-ac4aac4811d1', '9Du3Bn3cNPmKVZqqDgRz', 'null', 'null', '1', '2023-04-25',null, NULL),('f9f30fe2-d88c-4420-afc0-769fc1f745fb', '9Du3Bn3cNPmKVZqqDgRz', 'null', 'null','1', '2023-04-25', null, '{HUGE_JSON_ENTRY}');
 INSERT INTO `sessions` VALUES ('1b9b0452-1c53-4466-92b2-c3373ce4ab67', '9Du3Bn3cNPmKVZqqDgRz', null, 'null', '1', '2023-04-25',null, 'null'),('1ef7d5d7-b795-4e4c-a29d-e16ba880a522', '9Du3Bn3cNPmKVZqqDgRz', 'null','null', '1', '2023-04-25', null, '{HUGE_JSON_ENTRY}');
 INSERT INTO `sessions` VALUES ('d6529933-0e18-426c-8793-9d1711d0c0aa', '4EBdY2RT5xC9fc9rfqnz', 'null', null,'1', '2023-04-25', null, 'null');
 ....
```

Comment: Without even looking at the efficiency of any of the regexs, the obvious suggestion is to run them as several separate commands, rather than one gigantic one which is doomed to hit some kind of limits at some point no matter what you do.  If it is a requirement to do it like that you haven't mentioned why?

Comment: Please update your question and post the desired/expected output.

Comment: Do the input files have a lot of long lines joined by `),(`? Because even if the first `-e` command splits them with newlines, the rest will continue to work on one original line at a time, which may affect performance.

Comment: Inserting `\n` followed by searches using `^` and `$` smells bad. How long are the original unsplit lines typically? You can merge some s/// eg. `',1,'` and `',0,'` and I'd be surprised if not some of the NULL ones too

Comment: some of your regex look like candidates for [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: should `('.*',)` be `('[^']*',)` ?

Comment: I thnk `s/^(.*',)`[...] , etc, will have to do a lot of backtracking (when input is long) before they discover there is no possible match

Comment: The following page contains hints why it is not useful to use the output of `ls`: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck.

Comment: Do you really need all the replacements? Like @jhnc suggested, What happens when you remove all instructions for `NULL` and use ` "s/(^|,) *null(,|$) */\1 NULL\2 /gi"` ? With `"s/,1,/, 1, /g"` the previous `"s/',1,'/', 1, '/g"` seems redundant.

Comment: Can you isolate the statements that make it fail? Are all files (relative to their size) slow or only one file that might have something special in the json?
When you repeat the example sql many times, will it be just as slow?

Comment: Are you missing a comma in `s/\),\(/\n/g`, do you want `s/\),\(/,\n/g`?

Comment: `sed -i` is always a bad idea.  Using it with a large number of files makes it worse.  Using it with a `sed` command that you already know is having difficulty is a terrible idea.  Why risk the data corruption?  It would probably be easier to just delete all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using pipelines? For multi-core, performance may be better with parallel processing.

example:

```
....
| while read F; do
sed -E 's/\),\(/\n/g' $F |
sed -E "s/','/', '/g" |
sed -E "s/^INSERT\sINTO\s\`.*\`\sVALUES\s*\((.*)\);$/\1/g" |
....
sed -E "s/(.*[0-9]{1}),'/\1, '/g" |
sed -E "s/([0-9]{1}),([0-9]{1})/\1, \2/g" |
sed -E "s/NULL,([[:digit:]])/NULL, \1/g"
> workFile;
mv workFile $F;
....
```

Comment: When a line end with a pipe `|`, you don't have to escape the newline `\\`.

Comment: @Walter A
Thanks. Corrected the answer.